# What's the best way to migrate a Confluence site to Sharepoint?

Tags: migration, third-party-software, confluence

We have an internally hosted Confluence site that we're trying to move to a cloud hosted Sharepoint.com site.  What's the best way to migrate those pages while keeping as much of it intact as possible.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few third party tools that may be of assistance, I know [Metalogix](http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Content-Matrix.aspx) has one and [Tzunami](http://www.tzunami.com/products/td-confluence-migration/). Also Atlssian has a Sharepoint connector that might be beneficial, it allows the content to be surfaced in Sharepoint while still residing in Confluence. Going to SP Online though it might not work.

Answer (score 2):

I channeled all the joy(?) and pain SharePoint has given me the last years into building a tool that does exactly this: migrate pages from Confluence to SharePoint Online: WikiTraccs. Check it out if you like at https://www.wikitransformationproject.com

As target it supports SharePoint Online only and creates standard modern pages that could've been created by users. Attachments etc. are migrated as well. See what it can to and not do [over here](https://www.wikitransformationproject.com/docs/features/).

Feel free to reach out if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Enterprise Bridge](http://caseagile.com/products/enterprise-bridge/confluence-to-sharepoint-migration/), which automates migration of Confluence to SharePoint. It supports Confluence on premise servers and Confluence online, SharePoint 2010, 2013, 2016 and SharePoint Online. The tool transfers text, images, tables, wiki pages, documents, files, videos etc. Conversion includes users, groups, permissions, modification dates and relative links.

Answer (score -2):

You may try using Vyapin's DocKIT for SharePoint as it allows you import content into a cloud. The SharePoint migration task can be done easily if you can move the Confluence content to a central repository like a file server or exposed as file shares. Once this is taken care of, DocKIT can easily import all the converged content to the cloud SharePoint. Try this - 
http://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint-migration/dockit/sharepoint-migration.htm
and inform about the result.

Comment: Please note that, [per the FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.  [mod]